# check if directed graph exists using ford fulkerson

Tags: graph-theory

Using Ford - Fulkerson algorithm, check if a directed graph with following degrees exists:
$ d^+(x_1) = 2, d^-(x_1) = 2, d^+(x_2) = 0,  d^-(x_2) = 1, $
$d^+(x_3) = 2, d^-(x_3) = 2, d^+(x_4) = 1, d^-(x_4) = 0 $

I know the algorithm and I know how to find max flow, but how to use it to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd really like to see the solution your friend worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_realization_problem) refers to two methods for solving this problem, neither of which is the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. There is the [Kleitman-Wang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleitman%E2%80%93Wang_algorithms) algorithm (actually, two different algorithms), and the [Fulkerson-Chen-Anstee Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulkerson%E2%80%93Chen%E2%80%93Anstee_theorem).

Comment: I had to use this algorithm, cause this was an excercise literally taken from an exam. Actually, my friend worked it out ;) thanks anyway!

Comment: Please post the solution your friend worked out. It would be nice to have a record of the method here on m.se.

Answer (score 0):

We duplicate the set of vertices of graph, indexing them $ x_1 ^\prime, \dots x_4^\prime $ and $ x_1 ^{\prime\prime}, \dots x_4^{\prime\prime} $. We connect every $x_i ^\prime$ with $ x_j ^{\prime\prime} $ for $i \neq j$. Then we add a source $s$, connected with all vertices $ x ^\prime $, and a sink $t$, connected with all vertices $ x ^{\prime\prime} $ (all arcs are directed from $s$ to $t$). The capacity of $(s, x_i ^\prime)$ is equal to $d^+(x_i)$, $c(x_j ^{\prime\prime}, t) = d^-(x_j)$ and $c(x_i ^\prime,x_j ^{\prime\prime})=1$ for $i,j=1,\dots,4 \quad (i \neq j)$.

This makes a network, in which we can apply the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. This should work, as the answer for the question if the graph exists is "yes", when maximum flow is equal to $[V(G)\setminus \{t\}, t]$ - cut (which is $5$ in this case) and "no", when max flow is less than $[V(G)\setminus \{t\}, t]$ - cut. Here the answer is no, if I am right.
Any comments are welcome :)